# Calling too many getters

Tags: apex, visualforce, debugging

I have the following VisualForce Page:

```
    <apex:page controller="Checkbox_Class" Tabstyle="Asset">
    <apex:form > 
        <apex:pageBlock Title="Assets with CheckBoxes">
            <div style="overflow:auto; width:500px; height:500px">  
                <apex:pageBlockSection Title="List of Available Assets">
                    <apex:dataTable value="{!assets}" var="a" columnswidth="50px,50px" cellpadding="4" border="1">
                        <!--makes a call to the getAssets() method in the Checkbox_Class Controller-->
                           <apex:column >
                                    <apex:facet name="header">
                                        <apex:inputCheckbox>
                                            <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" onsubmit="checkAll(this,'checkedone')"/>
                                        </apex:inputCheckbox>
                                    </apex:facet>
                            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!a.selected}" id="checkedone"></apex:inputCheckbox>
                            </apex:column>
                            <apex:column headervalue="Asset Name" value="{!a.acc.Name}" />
                            <apex:column headervalue="Serial Number" value="{!a.acc.SerialNumber}" />
                            <apex:column headervalue="Quantity" value="{!a.acc.Quantity}" />    
                            <apex:column headervalue="RMAed" value="{!a.acc.RMAed__c}" />
                    </apex:dataTable>   
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
           </div>
                <apex:pageBlockSection Title="Selected Assets" >
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!getSelected}" value="Create Quote"/>
                    <apex:outputText value="{!SelectedAssets}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>                
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>

<script>
function checkAll(cb)
{
var inputElem = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(var i=0; i<inputElem.length; i++)
{
    if(inputElem[i].id.indexOf("checkedone")!=-1)
inputElem[i].checked = cb.checked;
}
}   
</script>

</apex:page>
```

The visualforce page above basically creates a checkbox data table like here: http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Checkbox_in_DataTable. 
The javascript at the bottom has been modified to Select All AND Deselect All.

The problem is that I get the "Collection size 1100 exceeds the maximum size of 1000" error. I thought I would fix this by limiting my Query to 100 records. This does not work. 
I checked how many times I am calling a get method and it seems that this is the problem. In my visualforce code, it seems that it's calling the getassets method from my controller (this is represented by !assets). However, after this, it seems another getter called GetSelectedAssets gets called immediately without any provacation from my part. That is what is causing this error. However, since I'm not calling this anywhere right now without a prompt, I can't figure out how to fix it.

Here is my Controller code just to provide added information:

```
public class Checkbox_Class
{

List<assetswrapper> assetsList = new List<assetswrapper>(); 
List<Asset> selectedAssets = new List<Asset>();
Integer x;

public List<assetswrapper> getAssets() 
{


    //String entId=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id') ;// getting Entitlement Id parameter from the current entitlement page
    for(Asset a : [Select //Select Asset name, Serial Number, Quantity and whether it's been RMAed from Assets
                   SerialNumber, Name, Quantity, Returned__c, Retired__c, RMAed__c 
                    FROM Asset
                    WHERE (Retired__c != true AND Returned__c != true) //AND Entitlement__c=:entId //ignore all Retired and Returned Assets.
                    limit 100] )    //Only choose Assets from a certain Entitlement ID. Limit the amount of returned Assets to 500 because of SOQL 1000 query limit.


    // Limited to 500 so as to not overcollect, if greater than 500, user might want to upgrade to an Enterprise Class
    assetsList.add(new assetswrapper(a)); //as each asset is processed, we create a new assetswrapper object and add it to the assetslist
    system.debug('getassets');
    return assetsList; // return the assetsList list when called. 

}

public PageReference getSelected()
{//We create a new list of Assets that we populate only with Assets if they get selected
    selectedAssets.clear(); //
   //cycle through assetswrapper accwrapper list and we will check to see if the selected property is set to true, 
   //if it is, we add the Asset to the selectedAssets list. 
    for(assetswrapper accwrapper : assetsList)
    if(accwrapper.selected == true)
    selectedAssets.add(accwrapper.acc);
   system.debug('getSelected');
    return null;

}

 public void getSelected2()
{//same as the above method. Except we just want to return an integer value here to see how many assets were selected. 
   //selectedAssets.clear(); //
    for(assetswrapper accwrapper : assetsList)
        if(accwrapper.selected == true)
            selectedAssets.add(accwrapper.acc);        
    x = selectedAssets.size();    
    system.debug('getSelected2');    
}


public Integer GetSelectedAssets()
{
    if(selectedAssets.size()>0){
    x = selectedAssets.size();
    system.debug('getSelectedAssetsx');
     return x;
    }
    //return selectedAssets;

    else
    system.debug('getSelectedAssetsnull');
    return null;

} 


//The wrapper/container class. Wrapper contains both the Asset object and a boolean value. 
public class assetswrapper
{
    public Asset acc{get; set;}
    public Boolean selected {get; set;}
   //When we create a new assetswrapper object here, we pass an asset. Selected value is also set to False. 
    public assetswrapper(Asset a)
       {
        acc = a;
        selected = false;

      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you are doing any DML statements, so set the page's readOnly attribute to true.  That increases the limits on collection sizes to 10,000.

```
 <apex:page controller="Checkbox_Class" Tabstyle="Asset" readOnly="true">
```

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_page.htm

> **readOnly**:  A Boolean value that enables read-only mode for a
>   Visualforce page. In read-only mode, a page may not execute any DML
>   operations, but the limit on the number of records retrieved is
>   relaxed from 50,000 to 1 million rows. It also increases the number of
>   items in a collection that can be handled by iteration components,
>   from 1,000 to 10,000. If not specified, this value defaults to false.

Comment: Did this fix it?

Comment: if this answer fixed the problem, please mark the answer as the "solution"  :)

Answer (score 0):

Any time you access getAssets, it increments your assetList by at most 100 items.  This could very well lead to a collection size limitation if your page is hit multiple times.  Either move the logic for the SOQL query into the constructor, or add an if check to see if the assets list is already populated.

Furthermore, there's really no need to store the selected assests in another list variable.  I would just reuse the selected attribute in your list of asset wrappers.